# Running Java applications as a service - startup error captures?

Tags: java, windows-services, jboss

I'm in the arduous process of trying to upgrade a couple of our servers to use a current version of the application installed on it and I've gotten a bit stuck.  I've gotten everything replaced and have narrowed my issue down to 1 .jar file.  If I use the new version of this specific file, I can not get the service to start, and using the old version (and the new version of every other file), it runs fine.

When I try to start the service I get this message: `Could not start <service> service on Local Computer.  The service did not return an error.  This could be an internal Windows error or an internal service error.`

I've looked in the event viewer, and all it has are these entries every time I try to start it:

`<Service> has started`

`Could not find the service start class`

`<service> has failed to start`

Is there some place else that I can look that might be able to give a bit more information on why it's failing to start?

We are using the 'JavaService' utility to create the windows process. This server is also running jboss.

EDIT: I have also determined that it is not an issue with my SQL database as I just did all of the upgrades between the versions.  I still can't get it to start with the new .jar, and the old .jar still works.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe that's obvious, but have you tried to run the very same command (as in service definition) manually?

Comment: @Grzegorz I have, nothing happens when I try to run it from the command line, it just immediately returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue!

After days and days of looking around at configuration files, I finally noticed something: We are now using log4j for logging but it wasn't included in the .jar's manifest! I added it to the manifest and it now starts up!

Thanks for your help everyone :]

Answer (score 2):

You can't execute a java application as a service. Windows services implement a specific interface that java.exe or javaw.com do not. You will need a wrapper to implement this functionality. One such wrapper is http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org.

Answer (score 1):

As Pierre mentioned, you can't run java **directly** as a Windows service. [Apache commons daemon (a.k.a. Procrun)](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html) is another tool that will adapt a java application for use as a Windows service.

Comment: We use the 'JavaService' utility to use java applications as a windows service

Comment: @user564636: Please add that information to your question, I think it is relevant.